# How to access documentDB query execution plans

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to look at documentDB query plans to determine benefit of indexes for multi-column "where" condition queries. Because of https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query/#comment-2846688070 (one of the comments regarding For and In query execution plans), I am getting a feeling that it should be possible to view the execution plans. I am not able to find syntax anywhere.

Comment: I do not believe there is a way to see this as of this time. You have to experiment. However, I think it would be very useful. Add a User Voice for it here and I'll vote for it: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb

Comment: @LarryMaccherone here you go https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/15959218-provide-constructs-to-look-at-the-query-execution

Comment: OK. I upvoted it. :-)